# fputcsv adding strange characters at the end of fields

Tags: php, mysql, csv, encryption

I have a form that encrypts and stores the users entries. I then have an export feature which allows an admin to decrypt and export a csv of all entries.

It decrypts fine, and if I print my array on to the page it all looks fine, but when I generate the CSV it adds odd symbols after some of the data, when opening in notepad or excel there are question marks, music symbols, diamonds and other odd characters in the some of cells, but not all. I can't spot a pattern - if I add "Miss" or "Mr" in to the title field it adds the characters, if I add my name (Zoe) it doesn't! My data is stored as BINARY but I have changed some fields to VARCHAR and it makes no difference, I have also tried utf8_encoding my data.

This is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Title', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Address', 'Age', 'Email', 'I am...'));
$encryption_key = ""; 

//then I do my database select

foreach ( $theresults as $result ) {

//then I decrypt my data and pass it in to variables

$responses = array($title,$fname,$lname,$address,$age,$emailadd,$who);
fputcsv($output, $responses);

}
```

One thing I have noticed is when I open it in notepad the quotes around each element are inconsistent (this is obivously without the odd chars as it doesn't copy them in to stackoverflow):

```
Title,"First Name","Last Name",Address,Age,Email,"I am..."
Miss,Zoe,Tester,,29,,other
Zoe,Zoe,Zoe,Zoe,29,,other
Mr,Test,Testington,"an address",35,,diagnosed
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can't find any posts within similar problems anywhere!

Comment: And if you look really closely, you'll see that these inconsistent quotes are consistently around strings that contain space characters

Comment: Maybe decryption encryption/decryption is broken, not `fputcsv`. Try simply printing/dumping your data and check for odd characters. If they are present then you must look at your encryption/decryption (maybe some padding issues?).

Comment: I've tried a couple of things to remove trailing spaces but this still happens...

Comment: There are no decryption issues, if I print my array it looks fine...

Comment: I have noticed that the odd characters make each field add up to 16 characters - but there are fields with 3, 5, 6 characters that don't have these strange characters...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more parameters in fputcsv, the delimiter and the enclosure.

```
fputcsv($output, array(...), ',', '"');
```

The delimiter should be `';'` in a CSV file. You'll get some problems with adresses if your delimiter is `','`.

Comment: Thanks, this doesnt resolve my issue with the weird characters though, they are still there...

Comment: By the way, how are you decrypting your datas ? Because you specify UTF-8 as charset. maybe it's because you're not dealing with this encoding.

Comment: I did try wrapping all my variables in utf8_encode() before putting them in to the array but it made no difference - unless there is a better/alternative way?